# FTDI chip used by Android 2.3.6

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, peripherals

Is it possible to use FTDI chip with Android 2.3.6? I've found [an application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ftdi.ft31x.hyperterm) which works with FTDI chip, but it uses Android 3.1 and later.

I'd like connect my phone to peripheral hardware over UART. [This company](http://www.ftdichip.com/Android.htm) provides the FTDI chip which can be used for it, and they provide an application (see above), but it's only for Android 3.1 and later. I'd like to use it with Android 2.3.6, but I think it's missing Android Open Accessory Protocol which is needed for it. Is there is another possibility to connect it to peripheral hardware?

Comment: Can you please go into a little more details of the purpose behind your question? It's hard to understand what you want to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: I'd like connect my phone to peripheral hardware over UART. [This company](http://www.ftdichip.com/Android.htm) provides the FTDI chip which can be used for it, and they provide an application (link in my question), but it's only for Android 3.1 and later. I'd like to use it with Android 2.3.6, but I think it's missing Android Open Accessory Protocol which is needed for it. I'd like to know if there is another possibility how to connect it to peripheral hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details! I integrated them with your question, and also updated the tags accordingly. Unfortunately that's all I can do for you so far -- but now your issue should be clearer for other "bypassers" who might know something. Good luck! -- Besides: Maybe an upgrade of your OS would be an option. If so, you might want to take a look into [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) while waiting for an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I think It's possible. But you need to port the sourcecode to support 2.3.6 API. You need install Google API Add On and follow the steps posted in android development page http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html

I think the sourcecode could be found in FTDI webpage.